Custom VBA Function to Convert to Base62
I'm trying to create a function in VBA that will encode a number into base62. If the encoded base62 string is less than 6 total characters, the functions pads the front of the string with zeros.
Function Base62Encode(ByVal num As Variant) As String
    Dim base62_chars As String
    base62_chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim base62 As String
    base62 = ""
    
    ' Encode using base62 conversion
    Do While num > 0
        base62 = Mid(base62_chars, (num Mod 62) + 1, 1) & base62
        num = Int(num / 62)
    Loop
    
    ' Pad with leading zeros to ensure 6-character length
    Base62Encode = String(6 - Len(base62), "0") & base62
End Function

The function works perfectly fine for all integers I pass to the function until I go past 2,147,483,647—then I get an error. I'm definitely a novice at vba, but it seems like the error has something to do with the Long integer data type range limit but I'm not sure how I can get around that problem.
I tried converting values throughout the function to the decimal data type as well, but I am still getting the error (which appear as a #VALUE! error in Excel)
Thanks in advance!

Try =Base62Encode(2147483647) (remove commas in the argument). I got 2LKcb1 in M365.

That works, but only because 2147483647 is the upper limit of the range that is working for me.
The same function using 214748364_8_ instead does not work (I only added commas in the body of my question as a visual aid).
Thanks though!

@taller - I think the OP is using that to highlight the digit for your benefit.

Yep my apologies for that. I thought I could italicize the digit that was changed, but it didn't accept my attempt to use the in-comment formatting (ie please just ignore the underscores)

If you have 64-bit Excel you could use the LongLong data type which has a limit of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807

@RonRosenfeld - Can you create an answer around that. I can't seem to.

@Chon - As soon as you go from 2147483647 to 2147483648 VBA changes the Variant type from Long to Double.

@Enigmativity You need to use the equivalent Int function as the Mod function has some limitations with large numbers.

If your needed range is larger than what you can compute in VBA, I suggest you search the Internet for the XNumbers add-in. It runs on my 64-bit 365 and should run on earlier versions. It can calculate up to 32,760 significant digits.

@Enigmativity Actually, the problem in the function is the limitation of the MOD function and not the data type, as you can see in taller's solution.


As per the MS documentation, both arguments should be 'any numeric expression.' It does not explicitly state whether large number (eg. LongLong) is supported.

Microsoft documentation:

Mod operator


It seems this is a limitation of the Mod operator. Please try using a express with Int function  as a replacement. (Thanks for @Gserg's comment)

Function Base62Encode(ByVal num As Variant) As String
    Dim base62_chars As String
    base62_chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    Dim base62 As String
    base62 = ""
    ' Encode using base62 conversion
    Do While num > 0
'        base62 = Mid(base62_chars, (num Mod 62) + 1, 1) & base62
        base62 = Mid(base62_chars, (num - Int(num / 62) * 62) + 1, 1) & base62
        num = Int(num / 62)
    Loop
    ' Pad with leading zeros to ensure 6-character length
    Base62Encode = String(6 - Len(base62), "0") & base62
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim i As Double
    For i = 2147483647 To 2147483650#
        Debug.Print i, Base62Encode(i)
    Next
End Sub

Output:
 2147483647   2LKcb1
 2147483648   2LKcb2
 2147483649   2LKcb3
 2147483650   2LKcb4


Split(num1 / num2, ".")(0) - why? You literally copied Int(num / 62) few lines earlier, could you at least use that, even if you weren't aware of the integer division operator, \? Apart from being a horrible and uncalled for invocation of strings, it won't even work on locales that use , as the decimal comma.

@Gserg It rounddowns the result of num1 / num2.  You are right. Int is the right choice. Thanks

It seems the operator \ has same limitation as Mod . It doesn't work with large numbers. eg. ?2147483648 \ 62
